# why doesn't my child component work?

Tags: vue.js

Data can be passed down to child components using props. But why doesn't my tag child work?It doesn't print out hello.Here is my code,
html:

```
<div id="app">
   <child message="hello"></child>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app'
});

Vue.component('child',{
  props:['message'],
  template:"<span>{{message}}</span>"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You component needs to be declared before your main Vue instance:

```
Vue.component('child',{
  props:['message'],
  template:"<span>{{message}}</span>"
})

new Vue({
  el:'#app'
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxeb7gmo/

Answer (score 0):

You must dynamically bind it by adding : in front of message like this

```
:message="hello"
```

Comment: Could you show me how to do it? I try this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are u setting the value of mmessage in the child

Comment: You should pass the value of the message from the parent

Comment: `v-bind` binds the prop to a `javascript` value (usually declared in data), if you want to pass a string literal then you don't need to use it.